# PgSQL not compiling RETURNING ... INTO

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a view, and am trying to create an INSERT RULE for it.

This is my code:

```
CREATE VIEW v_Telecontagem AS
  SELECT
    Fonte.id                   AS id,
    Fonte.nome                 AS fonte_nome,
    Fonte.tipo_fonte           AS fonte_tipo_fonte,
    Telecontagem.id_fornecedor AS telecontagem_id_fornecedor,
    Telecontagem.fornecedor    AS telecontagem_fornecedor,
    Telecontagem.nome          AS telecontagem_nome,
    Telecontagem.id_fonte      AS telecontagem_id_fonte
  FROM Telecontagem
    INNER JOIN Fonte ON Telecontagem.id_fonte = Fonte.id;

CREATE RULE v_Telecontagem_INSERT AS ON INSERT TO v_Telecontagem DO INSTEAD (
  INSERT INTO Fonte (id, nome, tipo_fonte) VALUES (DEFAULT, NEW.fonte_nome, NEW.fonte_tipo_fonte)
  RETURNING id INTO NEW.telecontagem_id_fonte;

  INSERT INTO Telecontagem (id_fornecedor, fornecedor, nome, id_fonte)
  VALUES (NEW.telecontagem_id_fornecedor, NEW.telecontagem_fornecedor, NEW.telecontagem_nome, NEW.telecontagem_id_fonte)
);
```

My INSERT happens in two steps, first it inserts into `Fonte` table, then it inserts into `Telecontagem` table.

For this I need to "store" the new `id` from the first insert, therefore I am trying to use `RETURNING id INTO NEW.telecontagem_id_fonte`.

However PgSQL complains telling me that `INTO` is not expected after the `RETURNING`:

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTO" at character ...`

Can't I use this within a `RULE`? How can I perform this insert operation if I can't store the newly created `id`?

Comment: You should use an instead trigger to make the view updateable.

Comment: It  works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution @a_horse_with_no_name suggested was using a trigger like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION v_Telecontagem_func()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    BEGIN
        IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
            INSERT INTO Fonte (id, nome, tipo_fonte) VALUES (DEFAULT, NEW.fonte_nome, NEW.fonte_tipo_fonte) RETURNING id INTO NEW.telecontagem_id_fonte;
            INSERT INTO Telecontagem (id_fornecedor, fornecedor, nome, id_fonte) VALUES (NEW.telecontagem_id_fornecedor, NEW.telecontagem_fornecedor, NEW.telecontagem_nome, NEW.telecontagem_id_fonte);
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
            -- UPDATE HERE
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
            -- DELETE HERE
            RETURN NULL;
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$function$;

CREATE TRIGGER v_Telecontagem__trig
    INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON
    v_Telecontagem FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE v_Telecontagem_func();
```

Basically, for the same view, I am now using a function and a trigger to execute the function on `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.